# Need some PHP help for making a change to wordpress plugin Groups

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm really in a jam here.  I am extremely close to launching my wordpress site.  I have one rather large obstacle in my way that should be an easy fix.  I am beginner level php so I am really struggling on this and any help or direction would be extremely appreciated since I have been trying to solve this issue for two weeks through reading and research.

Here is the issue and I will try to be as detailed as possible:

1. I have a custom post type called Portfolio.
2. I have a Portfolio page where it loads all of the featured images of
   the Portfolio Posts into a grid on the Portfolio Page.  You know a
   basic portfolio setup where if you click the image it takes you to
   the portfolio post.
3. Using the Groups plugin, when I restrict access to a Portfolio Post,
   it removes the featured image from the Portfolio Page grid. Like the
   post doesn't exist for non group members.
4. I am trying to sell access to these Portfolio Posts so if someone is
   not a member they will not know there is anything there to buy.

I don't know how to make it to where those featured images still show on the Portfolio Page.  I need people to know they are there but not be able to access them.  As I mentioned in the support question, I cannot use a shortcode for this because the video is hard coded in to my theme.  I need to add it to the code in a custom plugin to change groups to not remove that featured image from my portfolio page regardless of the restriction on the post.

I have gone through the [API](http://api.itthinx.com/groups) and found the section that controls access to the restricted posts.  The Class is Groups-Post-Access.  When both of these are removed from the class-groups-access.php I am able to see the featured images on the Portfolio page but it also removes the function that restricts the actual post.  I don't know how I could tell the plugin to only return the featured image but still hide access to the post.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', array( __CLASS__, 'posts_where' ), 10, 2 );

/**
     * Filters out posts that the user should not be able to access.
     * 
     * @param string $where current where conditions
     * @param WP_Query $query current query
     * @return string modified $where
     */
    public static function posts_where( $where, &$query ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        // this only applies to logged in users
        if ( $user_id ) {
            // if administrators can override access, don't filter
            if ( get_option( GROUPS_ADMINISTRATOR_ACCESS_OVERRIDE, GROUPS_ADMINISTRATOR_ACCESS_OVERRIDE_DEFAULT ) ) {
                if ( user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) ) {
                    return $where;
                }
            }
        }

        // 1. Get all the capabilities that the user has, including those that are inherited:
        $caps = array();
        if ( $user = new Groups_User( $user_id ) ) {
            $capabilities = $user->capabilities_deep;
            if ( is_array( $capabilities ) ) {
                foreach ( $capabilities as $capability ) {
                    $caps[] = "'". $capability . "'";
                }
            }
        }

        if ( count( $caps ) > 0 ) {
            $caps = implode( ',', $caps );
        } else {
            $caps = '\'\'';
        }

        // 2. Filter the posts that require a capability that the user doesn't
        // have, or in other words: exclude posts that the user must NOT access:

        // The following is not correct in that it requires the user to have ALL capabilities:
//      $where .= sprintf(
//          " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta on {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id WHERE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '%s' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value NOT IN (%s) ) ",
//          self::POSTMETA_PREFIX . self::READ_POST_CAPABILITY,
//          $caps
//      );

        // This allows the user to access posts where the posts are not restricted or where
        // the user has ANY of the capabilities:
        $where .= sprintf(
            " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN " .
            " ( " .
            "   SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '%s' ) " . // posts without access restriction
            "   UNION ALL " . // we don't care about duplicates here, just make it quick
            "   SELECT post_id AS ID FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '%s' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value IN (%s) " . // posts that require any capability the user has
            " ) ",
            self::POSTMETA_PREFIX . self::READ_POST_CAPABILITY,
            self::POSTMETA_PREFIX . self::READ_POST_CAPABILITY,
            $caps
        );

        return $where;
    }

add_filter( 'the_posts', array( __CLASS__, "the_posts" ), 1, 2 );

/**
     * Filter posts by access capability.
     * 
     * @param array $posts list of posts
     * @param WP_Query $query
     */
    public static function the_posts( $posts, &$query ) {
        $result = array();
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            if ( self::user_can_read_post( $post->ID, $user_id ) ) {
                $result[] = $post;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

If someone can give me a better understanding of what is happening here and maybe an example of what he is referring to by creating a template for my custom post type, I would really appreciate it.  Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: In order to help, we'll need to know : what you have tried, what are the errors. To be honnest, if you provided them with as much information you have provided us, I'm not surprise they couldnt help... what's the link to the plug in forum post ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am pretty sure he understood what I meant with him being the plugin author.  Sorry for it being a little vague.  I updated the question to include the code from the api.  The link to the [support question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-restrict-content-from-only-logged-in-members?replies=5#post-5505060).  I asked the question in a different way because a similar question had been asked and he returned the same answer as mine with no info on how one might go about making the changes.  So that is why I asked it the way I did on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using wordpress to handle hiding a specific category vs changing the actual plugin code.